# How to validate user using extjs coding?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

I am newer in Ext JS (sencha) Programming.
I designed a login form and user home form using exjs.
I create a controller, a model , views (for login and userhome) and store for user Info.
I also create a json file(userInfo.json) containing user details like user name and password

I do not know how to fire a event on login button click and check user if exist in json file. and return true or false.

Comment: Why not sending an ajax request to the json file, get the user info, compare the username and password ?

Comment: You shouldn't have a file that contains the login information. You should send password and username to the server, do a server-side check and only deliver protected information if the password check on the server is successful. Everything else is the same as no password check at all.

Comment: (If you don't believe me, send me the url and I tell you all the username/password combinations)